# Reusable HttpResponse in android network programming?

Tags: android, http, networking

As using the network package which apache provides, we usually do :

```
HttpResponse resp = httpClient.execute(httpRequest);
```

When I retrieve the HttpEntity object of the response, open the InputStream and extract the data in it, the HttpResponse object becomes unusable. If I try to do the thing again, exception occurs.

Here I wish to reuse the HttpResponse, mostly for caching. But the HttpResponse object returned is type interface, I cannot call clone.

Is there any way I can reuse the HttpResponse ?

Answer (score 1):

I think this behavior is by concept and cannot be changed. Why don't you cache the data you read from the response? You've already read them so why not store them somewhere where they can be centrally accessed?

Comment: Eh, ya I can implement the cache mechanism in layer above network. But I think if the caching is generic for various business scenario, I wish to do it in the network layer. This is what I`m exploring...